# Firebase listener, for specific child values, on child not yet created

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data structure like so:

```
friend_requests_sent:

    userId1:
        sub_userId1:
            status: "request_sent"
        sub_userId2:
            status: "request_sent"
        sub_userId3:
            status: "request_failed"

    userId2:
        sub_userId1:
            status: "request_sent"
        sub_userId2:
            status: "request_failed"
        sub_userId3:
            status: "request_sent"
```

Each `sub_userId` is created at some point in time, but I want to set up a database listener that will be triggered only when the value of `status` is set to `request_sent` for a `sub_userId`.

I.e., I am trying to create an observer on the non-existing (yet) path `/friend_requests_sent/userId1/sub_userId4/status` that will check if it is indeed `request_sent`, **both when it is created and when the `status` value changes afterwards.**

How can I get back a snapshot of the former? Feels like I got lost in the firebase querying system.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This sounds like a job for firebase cloud functions. What exactly do you want to do when that path changes... Do you want to update some part of the database...

Comment: No I want to update the UI

Answer (score 0):

```
friend_requests_sent:
    userId1:
        requests:
          sub_userId1: "insertstatushere"
          sub_userId2: "insertstatushere"
          //continue
```

I think this would be a lot better. Add a child added, removed and changed for that path only (userIDHere/requests/). This way you can check and handle everything.

Comment: Thanks but I have other stuff in there than the "status" field (timestamp) so I guess can't really do that :s

Comment: That comment is actually key to your problem: you seem to want to display a list based on the status of the entries. In that case you should keep precisely that in the database: a list with the status of the entries. Even if you also keep the status data elsewhere, to display it in your UI the most direct mapping from database to UI is likely the easiest to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I suggest:

```
firebase.database().ref("friend_requests_sent").once('value', function(snap){

     snap.forEach(function(child){
        //For each userID below query looks for subusers whose status are 'request_sent'

        child.ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo('request_sent').on('child_added', function(grandChild){
          //grandChild.val() is the sub-user of child.val()
          //grandChild.val().status is equal to 'request_sent'
          alert(grandChild.val().status);
        });
     });

)};
```

Hope that works!